# Reading from a textfile and putting information into an array

Tags: perl, split

I'm trying to calculate the GCD of true random numbers using random.org and grabbing those numbers from a text file. Here is a program to do the above with a PRNG that I created earlier.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $range = 100;
my $gcdcount = 0;
sub gcd_iter($$) {
    my ($u, $v) = @_;
    while ($v) {
       ($u, $v) = ($v, $u % $v);
    }
    return abs($u);
}
for (my $count=0; $count<=5000; $count++) {
    my $random_numx = int(rand($range));
    my $random_numy = int(rand($range));
    my @pair = ($random_numx, $random_numy);
    if (gcd_iter($random_numx, $random_numy) == 1) {
        $gcdcount++; 
    }
}
print "The GCD Count for PRNG #1 is $gcdcount\n";
```

I'm pretty much doing the same exact thing, but grabbing the numbers from the textfile. How do I get those number pairs into a format where I can assign them variables in order to put them through the formula after I split the lines? Here is what I have so far:

```
my $filename = 'xxxxx';
open(my $fh, $filename)
or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
sub gcd_iter($$) {
     my ($u, $v) = @_;
     while ($v) {
         ($u, $v) = ($v, $u % $v);
    }
    return abs($u);
}
for (my $count=0; $count<=5000; $count++) {
     if (gcd_iter($) == 1) {
         $gcdcount++; 
     }
}
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    foreach ($row) {
        my @pair = split('s+', $_);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track but may benefit by typing

```
perldoc -f split
```

Perl has excellent built-in documentation.
I would change your lines:

```
foreach ($row) {
  my @pair = split('s+', $_);
}
```

to:

```
my @pair = split(/\s+/, $row);
```

and set `$num1` and `$num2` to `$pair[0]` and `$pair[1]` ... or simply use:

```
my ($num1, $num2) = split(/\s+/, $row);
```

to get the two scalars you are interested in directly.
In other words, you do not need the `foreach $row` line (you already have `$row`) and it is `\s` that is the shorthand pattern match for whitespace. 
Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Very nice answer. However, I think you missed a little bit. The `@pair` (or `$num1` and `$num2`) variable is lexical and nothing is done with it. OP needs to actually use it, print it or whatever.